# How to get new ng-repeat elements to animate background-color when added?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

How can I get the new elements added into an ng-repeat to animate the background-color?  I don't want existing elements that load with the page to animate, however.  Only the ones added when a button click event.

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="app">
      <main-component></main-component> 
    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

**Script.js**

```
console.clear();

function mainController() {
  var model = this;
  model.fields = [];
  model.fields.push("field1");
  model.fields.push("field2");

  model.addField = function(label) {
    console.log(label);
    model.fields.push(label);
  }
}

var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);

app.component("mainComponent", {
  template: `
    <button ng-click="model.addField('New Field')">Add Field</button><br /><br />
    <div class="field-container fadein" ng-repeat='f in model.fields track by $index'>{{f}}</div>
  `,
  controllerAs: "model",
  controller: [mainController]
});
```

**styles.css**

```
/* Styles go here */
.field-container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 80px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.fadein {
  background-color: white;
  transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
}
```

[Here's the plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/1lwcagB2MyODpLztFfIB?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the angular-animate classes for `ng-repeat` adding new items (i.e., `ng-enter`).

First you have to setup the initial state of the component:

```
.field-container {
  background-color: yellow;
  transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
}
```

Then you configure the behavior when the item is added, it'll have this state when it's just added and will roll back to the initial state in a few milliseconds:

```
.field-container.ng-enter {
  background-color: white;
}
```

Basically, when the item is just added, the item will have the `ng-enter` class added then the `css` sets the color to `white`. Later on, the class will be removed and the `css` will restore the state to `yellow` but in a smooth transition because of the `transition: background-color 1000ms linear;` configuration.

Here is a working fiddle that I took from [your plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/1lwcagB2MyODpLztFfIB?p=preview).

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);

app.component("mainComponent", {
  template: `
    <button ng-click="model.addField('New Field')">Add Field</button><br /><br />
    <div class="field-container fadein" ng-repeat='f in model.fields track by $index'>
      {{f}}
    </div>
  `,
  controllerAs: "model",
  controller: [mainController]
});

function mainController() {
  var model = this;
  model.fields = [];
  model.fields.push("field1");
  model.fields.push("field2");

  model.addField = function(label) {
    console.log(label);
    model.fields.push(label);
  }
}
```

```css
.field-container {
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  background-color: yellow;
  transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
}

.field-container.ng-enter {
  background-color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.8/angular-animate.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
  <main-component></main-component>
</div>
```

> Ref.: [ngRepeat Animations](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat)

Comment: Yes, you're right - this was easier but how can I get the initial (already created) fields from fading in.  I only want the new explicitly added fields to fade in.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare your fields to be objects instead of strings. Then you can use a `fadein` property. Set this property to true when you add a new field via the button click. You can then use `ng-class` to conditionally  apply styling to your new field object.

```
function mainController() {
  var model = this;
  model.fields = [];
  model.fields.push({name: "field1", fadein: false}); // Made field an object
  model.fields.push({name: "field2", fadein: false}); // Made field an object

  model.addField = function(label) {
    console.log(label);
    var field = {name: label, fadein: true}; // Make fadein true when we add the new field
    model.fields.push(field);
  }
}

var app = angular.module('app', ['ngAnimate']);

app.component("mainComponent", {
  template: `
    <button ng-click="model.addField('New Field')">Add Field</button><br /><br />
    <!--- ADDED NG-CLASS for determining fadein. Changed {{f}} to {{f.name}} --->
    <div class="field-container" ng-repeat='f in model.fields track by $index' ng-class="{'fadein': f.fadein == true}" >{{f.name}}</div>`,
  controllerAs: "model",
  controller: [mainController]
});
```

Comment: Both answers fit the bill but I'm going with this one for simplicity and I used strings for the demo but my arrays are really objects already so this works great. thanks!

Comment: @RichC you had to change your model data and add a huge ugly ng-class which will generate extra check for the digestion process as well, and all my answer does is to change a few css lines just the way angularjs tells you to do and you call this simplicity? You can tell that this one solves your problem better somehow, or it fits better your design or even it was easier (I don't know how) for you to use this approach, but you can't call it simple what so ever. *Disclaimer: I'm not telling this answer doesn't solve the problem, it's just not the better approach.*

Comment: Fair points - my thoughts were superficial from just looking over the code as I haven't implemented anything yet but I'll circle back around on this after I've completed my changes.